# Detect hover when dragging html element on touch device

Tags: ipad, html, drag-and-drop

When you are dragging an element using the touch events (DnD on touch screens), how do you detect that the object that you are dragging is over another object?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery is easy, add "collide: 'block'" or "collide: 'flag'" when you create a draggable.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/collidable

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any direct solution for this. One can have draggable element positioned "outside" dragging finger, but this didn't work in my case.

In my case, I had a grid-like element with fixed size child elements. Therefore it was easy to compare pageX/pageY of touchmove to the parent element and count the current element index by dividing the result with their dimensions.